# NLTK - Modifying nested for loop for multiprocessing

Tags: python, loops, nlp, nltk, python-multiprocessing

Currently, I have a nested for-loop that amends a list. I'm trying to create the same output while using multiprocessing.

My current code is,

```
for test in test_data:
    output.append([((ngram[-1], ngram[:-1],model.score(ngram[-1], ngram[:-1])) for ngram in 
    test])
```

Where test_data is a generator object, and model.score is from the NLTK package.

All the solutions I have found and tried, don't work (at least in my case).

**Is there a way to get the same output with multiprocessing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to multiprocessing, I believe the simplest way to do it is by using `joblib` package ... To use this package all you need to do is to create a function that takes one item of the generator and returns the result of one item.

In your case, it will look like so:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def func(test):
    return [((ngram[-1], ngram[:-1], model.score(ngram[-1], ngram[:-1])) for ngram in test]


output = Parallel(n_jobs=4, backend="threading")(
            delayed(func)(test) \
                for test in test_data)
```

Now, `output` is the output you are searching for. You can change the number of jobs as you like. However, I recommend setting it to `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` which is `4` in my case.

You can also check the [official documentation](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html) for more examples.

Comment: Thank you Anwarvic. I've come to the realisation, that the previous multiprocessing functions I created were correct (and yours!), the problem is the package NLTK still produces a slow result. For context, I'm running the function across ~300 million n-grams.